# how to place 2 Pick Views in the same controller in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to place 2 pick views in one view controller.  I tried setting different tags for them.  But both views have the "choices" array in them.  I control-dragged both and set to data source and delegate. I also tried the below code.  Thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,    UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var model =  Model()
    @IBOutlet weak var hoursTakenText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PickerView2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    let choices2 = ["0","0.7","1.0"]
    let choices: [String] = (1...90).map {  String($0)}
    @IBAction func hoursTaken(_ sender: Any) {
        subView.isHidden = false
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var subView: UIView!
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            return choices[row]}
        else {
            return choices2[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            return choices.count}
        else{
            return choices2.count
        }
    }
    //choices[row]: [String] = (1...10).map { "Option " + String(format: "%2d", $0)}
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let label = (view as? UILabel) ?? UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 15)
        //label.textColor = .blue
        label.textAlignment = .center
        //label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.text = choices[row]
        return label
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let hourstaken = Double(choices[row])
        print(hourstaken!)
        var stuDent: Student
        if pickerView  == pickerView1 {
            print(choices[row])
            stuDent = Student(hoursTaken: hourstaken!)
            model.student.append(stuDent)
        }
        subView.isHidden = true
        hoursTakenText.text = choices[row]
        print("hello")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //pickerViewBack.isHidden = true
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        subView.isHidden = true 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing between the two picker views in your implementation of `numberOfRowsInComponent` but not in your implementation of `viewForRow`. Your `viewForRow` always refers to `choices[row]` and sets the label's text from that. Therefore `choices` is displayed in both picker views.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't check which `UIPickerView` you are setting the rows for in `viewForRow`, so you set the same data for both.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = (view as? UILabel) ?? UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 15)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        label.text = choices[row]
    } else {
        label.text = choices2[row]
    }

    return label
}
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but it is pointless to say `(view as? UILabel)` as the incoming `view` will always be `nil`. I regard that as a bug, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags to do that

```
var pickerTags: Int = -1

func pickersCon(){
 self.pickerView1.tag = 1
 self.pickerView1.delegate = self
 self.pickerView2.tag = 2
 self.pickerView2.delegate = self
}
```

And in your pickerView methods you may do the following
For example

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return choices[row]}
    else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return choices2[row]
    }
}
```